# Does Exactness in Presheaves Imply Exactness in Sheaves?

Tags: sheaf-theory, sheaf-cohomology

I am reading Rotman, Introduction to Homological Algebra, and it reads that "Exactness of sheaves means exactness of stalks, which is usually different from exactness of presheaves." I don't think I am really understanding this sentence. Suppose $\mathcal{F}$,$\mathcal{G}$, $\mathcal{H}$ are sheaves of abelian group over a topological space $X$, and the following sequence
$$
\mathcal{F} \to \mathcal{G} \to \mathcal{H} 
$$ 
is exact as presheaves, which means for every $U$ open set,
$$
\mathcal{F}(U) \to \mathcal{G}(U) \to \mathcal{H}(U) 
$$ 
is exact. Then is it not implying that for all $x\in X$, a sequence of stalks
$$
\mathcal{F}_x \to \mathcal{G}_x \to \mathcal{H}_x
$$
exact? Does it not become a exact sequence of stalks if we take a limit over all open set $U$ containing $x$?

I suppose this is not true because the image of presheaf map is not always sheaf in $\mathcal{G}$, so the equalizer condition may not word in the image of $\mathcal{F}\to\mathcal{G}$. I am not so sure.

Is there any counterexample, or did I misunderstand the sentence?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I like to distinguish between sheaves and presheaves. Let $i$ be the forgetful functor; that is if $F$ is a sheaf, let $iF$ denote the reinterpretation as a presheaf. Let $a$ be the associated sheaf functor.

The crucial facts to know about $i$ and $a$ are that:

- $a$ is left adjoint to $i$

  - this implies $a$ is right exact; in fact it preserves all colimits
  - this implies $i$ is left exact; in fact it preserves all limits
- $a$ is furthermore left exact
- There is a natural isomorphism $\mathcal{F} \cong ai\mathcal{F}$ for sheaves $\mathcal{F}$.

This means that if you have an exact sequence of presheaves

$$ 0 \to \mathcal{P} \to \mathcal{Q} \to \mathcal{R} \to 0 $$

you also have an exact sequence of associated sheaves

$$ 0 \to a\mathcal{P} \to a\mathcal{Q} \to a\mathcal{R} \to 0 $$

However, if you have an exact sequence of sheaves

$$ 0 \to \mathcal{F} \to \mathcal{G} \to \mathcal{H} \to 0 $$

you can generally only expect a left exact sequence of the corresponding presheaves

$$ 0 \to i\mathcal{F} \to i\mathcal{G} \to i\mathcal{H} $$

Answer (score 7):

If $\mathcal{F}$, $\mathcal{G}$ and $\mathcal{H}$ are sheaves and fitting into an exact sequence 
$$0\to \mathcal{F}\to \mathcal{G}\to \mathcal{H} \to 0$$
in the category of *presheaves*, then the sequence is in fact exact as a sequence of *sheaves*. This follows (for example) from the fact that sheafification preserves finite limits and colimits.

However, if you're given an exact sequence in the category of *sheaves*, it may not be exact in the category of presheaves -- this failure is precisely what sheaf cohomology measures. Here is a simple example. Consider the exponential sequence 
$$\mathbb{Z}\overset{\times 2\pi i }{\to} \mathbb{C} \overset{{\rm exp}}{\to} \mathbb{C}^{\times}\;.$$
and the corresponding sequence of sheaves on $\mathbb{C}^{\times}=\mathbb{C}-\{0\}$ 
$$\underline{\mathbb{Z}}\to \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{C}^{\times}}\to \mathcal{O}^*_{\mathbb{C}^{\times}}\;.$$
This sequence is exact in the category of sheaves, but not in the category of presheaves. Indeed, if it were exact in presheaves then we would have a surjection on global sections 
$$\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{C}^{\times}}(\mathbb{C}^{\times})\overset{\rm exp}{\to} \mathcal{O}^*_{\mathbb{C}^{\times}}(\mathbb{C}^{\times}).$$
In particular, this would give the existence of a global complex logarithm.